# Convert DateTime in to integer

Tags: c#, datetime, biztalk

I am trying to return today's date as an integer. I have tried to return it as string and it is working fine. But how do I return it as an integer?

```
public string ConvertInvoiceDate()
{
    return DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
}
```

The integer should be in the same format of yyyyMMdd. The return type is string here because I was trying with string. Now I am not sure if I have to return as long/double. Using BizTalk I am trying to insert the a value in to the field in Oracle DB whose type is Numeric. When I tried to return as String it is throwing error as `The value for field "INVOICE_DTE" is invalid. ---> System.FormatException: The string '20170626' is not a valid AllXsd value.`

The detail of the field in the DB is below

[image]

Full error message is

```
A message sent to adapter "WCF-Custom" on send port "WcfSendPort_OracleDBBinding_Table_MACINVOICE_Custom" with URI "oracledb://xxxxx/" is suspended. 
 Error details: Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels.Common.XmlReaderParsingException: The value for field "INVOICE_DTE" is invalid. ---> System.FormatException: The string '20170626' is not a valid AllXsd value.
   at System.Xml.Schema.XsdDateTime..ctor(String text, XsdDateTimeFlags kinds)
   at System.Xml.XmlConvert.ToDateTime(String s, XmlDateTimeSerializationMode dateTimeOption)
   at Microsoft.Adapters.OracleCommon.OracleCommonMetadataUtils.ConvertXmlToLob(String text, XmlTypeCode xmlTypeCode, QualifiedType qualifiedType, String fieldName)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace: 
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.End(SendAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult result)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WcfClient`2.RequestCallback(IAsyncResult result) 
 MessageId:  {449B56A2-B053-47A4-826A-400B97CFB9A1}
 InstanceID: {DEA7CAA7-D589-4A4E-81A0-A2C6A961D340}
```

Comment: What do you mean return the date as an integer? What value should a date map to? Why is your function returning a string if you want a int?

Comment: `return 0`? Without defining what the integer actually represents, this question cannot be answered.

Comment: Your method is declared as returning a String, not an Int...

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: What is your *actual* problem? Why would you want to use an arbitrary number or string instead of an actual DateTime value? You *can* get a date-only object with `.Date`. All databases and Json libraries *can* treat DateTime as a date-only object.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am trying to insert the a value in to the field in Oracle DB whose type is Numeric. When I tried to return as String it is throwing error as `The value for field "INVOICE_DTE" is invalid. ---> System.FormatException: The string '20170626' is not a valid AllXsd value.`

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use the correct datatype in the DB?

Comment: It is an third party Database and cannot be changed

Comment: @Sid Oracle has a `date` type too. It would *not* have any problem converting a string to integer either. The error is *NOT* about string to integer conversion. That's an XML conversion error. XML dates typically follow the ISO8601 format.

Comment: @Sid post the *FULL* exception, including it's call stack. This looks like a client-side XML error. Also post *your data access code*. The problem isn't the string. Somehow, somewhere you are using XML. `System.FormatException` is *NOT* an Oracle exception, which means your XML code is the one that fails. Are you using an XmlDocument? DataTable?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have posted the full error message

Comment: @Sid which is obviously an XML error. It says you tried to pass an invalid `XsdDateTime` value. `xsd::datetime` is a string that uses the ISO8601 format, ie `2017-06-23T13:14:15Z`

Comment: @Milney  BizTalk is funny, you can return  a string to put it into a XML number or date field and it will work fine as long as you've formatted it correctly.  So that isn't the problem :-)

Answer (score 2):

Just convert them to integer before return, something like this:

```
public int ConvertInvoiceDate()
{
    return int.Parse(DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
}
```

[Try this Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rQgg7G)

Comment: the above code will give you the required value as integer, But I too confused about your actual requirement, can you please comment what you are going to do with this?

Comment: What you have and what he has would achieve the same output in the XML payload produced by BizTalk, so this is not likely to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to do something like this?

```
DateTime.Today.Ticks
```

It is `long`, not `int`. [Ticks property reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.datetime.ticks(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As Panagiotis Kanavos has said in the comments, the XML field is probably defined as an xsd::datetime that uses the ISO8601 format, ie `2017-06-23T13:14:15Z`

To achieve this you can either do the below, or more simply connect the datetime functoid to the node in the map.

```
public string ConvertInvoiceDate()
{
    return DateTime.Today.ToString("o");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This try again

```
int.Parse(DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString().Replace("-",""))
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for numeric value of DateTime object, there is a property Ticks, but it's long type, not int.

```
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.datetime.ticks(v=vs.110).aspx
```

Answer (score -1):

**Downvote totally wrong!  This Answer is based on the previous version of the question what was completely different**

**HOLD ON!**

Do not use a string or an integer.  You need to use TryParseExact() to return a DateTime.

Comment: He is using DateTime.Today, so no need to parse the date as he already has a date object.

Comment: @Pang The original version is still in the revision history as noted.